# Cwd.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xde00080)

Tags: perl, ubuntu, upgrade, perl-module, cpan

All Perl modules and 'cpan' stopped working after an upgrade of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Every time I run my script it leads to the error

```
threads.c: loadable library and Perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xde00080)
```

when I try to open cpan it shows

```
Cwd.c: loadable library and Perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xde00080)
```

I had installed "Cwd", "threads" modules in ubuntu 16.04 where Perl version was 5.22.1, whereas in ubuntu 18.04 the Perl version is 5.26.1.

I tried to remove the old version of modules but failed. I deleted content on ~/.cpan folder.

PS:
Everything works fine in root user.
if I run

```
sudo su
cpan
```

works perfectly. But as a normal user, I cant run any perl modules/scripts/cpan.

How do I correct the issue?
How can I re-install cpan or cpan modules?

I tried to reinstall Perl which did not help

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install perl
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libcwd-guard-perl
```

I installed cpan minus, cpan plus which gave the same error.

Comment: run the following to see where perl is picking up the bad libraries from:

$ strace  perl -e'use threads' 2>&1 | grep threads.so

If this shows that its trying to load it from a path containing
site_perl/, then that's where you may need to manually delete things.

As to why it works for root by not a normal user, you many have an
environment variable like PERL5LIB set. Try running both

which perl
perl -le'print for @INC'

as both root and non-root, and see whether there are any differences.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveMitchell Perl libraries used by root and the normal user was different, I manually deleted all the libraries which user was taking from. when I create a new user on the pc everything works fine. removing library path worked fine for me. thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

For solve problem next links can be used:

https://dev.to/foursixnine/about-perl-and-mismatched-binaries-346l
https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DBOOK/App-MigrateModules-0.002/script/perl-migrate-modules

Or in commands: (Replace  to your perl5 folder, in my case it was ~/perl5)

```
 mv <perl5> perl5_old
 cpan
 cpan App::MigrateModules
 perl-migrate-modules --from perl5_old /usr/bin/perl
```

Where perl5 your perl folder, usually in path exists in ENV variable PERL5LIB.

Comment: Don't be alarmed by passing `/usr/bin/perl` as the destination of `perl-migrate-modules`. As long as you have the `local::lib` environment variables configured, it'll make a new `~/perl5` directory (or whatever you have it set to) and migrate the modules into that folder.

Comment: This works, however it should be `cpan install App::MigrateModules`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by following https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/15861

I ran the command `perl -MCPAN -e 'recompile()'`

It recompile all the module, at last it worked.